# Position of Midpoint of Parallel Chords on an Ellipse

Tags: geometry

If there are chords in an ellipse which are parallel, and if there is a straight line that can cross all of the midpoints of these parallel chords, are all of the midpoints in the same vertical position (same position on the y axis)?

Comment: Your sentence is missing a verb.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Corrected

Comment: I still can't understand the question. Can you provide a figure ? Are you referring to conjugate diameters ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ok, I rephrased it, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: This is the property of conjugate diameters, see e.g. http://www.solitaryroad.com/c434.html

Answer (score 4):

The midpoints of any set of parallel chords of an ellipse will fall on a straight line segment.

To see this, think of viewing the ellipse obliquely along the major axis so it looks like a circle.  The midpiints look like they're on a straight line in that view, so the line will also look straight when you view the ellipse directly from "above".